# Angular - how to simulate HttpError response in service

Tags: angular, typescript, error-handling, mocking, http-error

How can I simulate HTTP error response in Angular service? I often need to handle different HTTP error codes and sometimes I need implement solution, but backend is not ready. How can I mock errors from backend?
Example code

```
  public getData(): Observable<Response> {
    return this.httpClient.get<Response>(`${this.endpoint}`);
  }
```

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Simplest solution - you can create an HttpErrorResponse instance, set error status and then return this object as service fake response.

```
  public getData(): Observable<Response> {
    const error = new HttpErrorResponse({ status: 422 });
    return of(error) as any;
  }

or 
  public getData(): Observable<Response> {
    const error = new HttpErrorResponse({ status: 422 });
    return throwError(error) as any;
  }
```

Comment: Why you posted question then?

Comment: Because I want share my knowledge, this is popular question. https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/07/01/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/

Comment: For rxjs 7.8 or greater you'll want to use the factory syntax  throwError(() => error);